# How to un-patch a directory/file on Linux?

Tags: linux, patch

How can I un-patch a file and a directory form a patched one.

I have applied both a patch `pd.patch` on a directory and a patch `pf.patch` on a file with those two commands:

```
patch -p1 < pd (in the directory) 

patch -p1 file_unpatch < pf.patch . ( will give me file_patch(patched file_unpatch))
```

How can i retrieve original `file_unpatch` and the `unpatched` directory?

**EDIT**
I have figured out we can un-patch a directory using the `-R` option:

```
patch -p1 -R < pd (in the directory) --> will give me unpatched directory.
```

Now, what about un-patching the file?

Comment: You should use a version control system (I recommend `git`) on your base tree. Then it is trivial to revert a particular file to its original state.

Answer (score 6):

As you found out, you just have to use `patch -R`to revert the patch.

Obviously, you have to unpatch in revert order, so in your case:

```
patch -R -p1 file_unpatch < pf.patch

patch -R -p1 < pd.patch
```